# ¿Como enviar el valor de mi radio button a mi input text?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Quiero enviar el valor de un radio button con dos opciones que se genera con JQuery, pero no logro enviarlo a mi input text, dejo mi codigo en la parte de abajo:

```
<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Direccion</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
           
               
            <div class="form-group" id=divInputColonia>
                <label asp-for="Colonia" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Colonia" class="form-control"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Colonia" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group" id=divRadioColonia hidden>
                <label asp-for="Colonia" class="control-label"></label>               
            </div>
                <div id="Coloniad"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

Este es mi codigo en JQuery

```
                 var radios = ['Del Valle Centro', 'Insurgentes San Borja'];
                    for (var value of radios)
                    {
                    $('#Coloniad')
                     .append(`<input type="radio" id="${value}" name="contact" value="${value}">`)
                     .append(`<label for="${value}">${value}</label></div>`);

                     $(value).change(function()
                     {
                         if(this.checked)
                         {
                             $("#Colonia").val(value)
                         }
                     })
                    } }
```

No se si estoy realizando bien mi codigo JQuery para realizar la asignacion del radio button al input text.

La vista genera esto en el navegador:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al seleccionar uno de los radiobuttons quiero mandar el valor respectivo al input text llamado Colonia.

[image]

Comment: Edita la pregunta, agrega el HTML que genera tu vista.

Comment: Creo que no me dejé entender, lo que tienes en tu vista en modo desarrollo != lo que genera el HTML en el navegador.

Comment: Ya subi la edicion.

Comment: Perdón, creo que el estrés me está pasando factura (cosas del trabajo), a lo que me refería era a que le veas el código HTML generado por la compilación de la vista, es decir, inspeccionar elemento o ver código fuente en el navegador. A veces, el problema está en que dos elementos comparten el mismo ID.

Comment: Lo he actualizado

Comment: 4 cosas: 1. Los ID del HTML no llevan espacio, vas a tener que eliminar los espacios en blanco antes de darle un append. 2. Una imagen en lugar de código disminuye la probabilidad de ayuda, esto lo afirmo basado en los más de 6 años que llevo en SOes. 3. Lectura sugerida con recomendaciones de cómo mejorar la pregunta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822. 4. Cambia también la variable `$(value).change` por motivo de los espacios.